# Does it really matter if I use text-mode vs. inline math?

Tags: math-mode, text-mode

I feel like this is sort of a stupid question but, I figure I'll ask anyways. I'm trying to typeset 2°, used in the sense of 'folio', the printing notation. I'm reasonably certain that context-wise, this would be a text-mode thing, not a math-mode thing. Having said that, any time I try to look up 'text-mode degree symbol latex', I get math-mode anyways. At this point I'm wondering, as a general practice, is it important not to use inline math for text, and if so, why?

Comment: Well for folio that’s not a degree sign but a superscripted o. I would write `\NewDocumentCommand{\folio}{}{2\textsuperscript{o}}`

Comment: As Don says you can define a new function as he shows, or if it is a oneoff use just use the `\textsuperscript{o}`
Note for a degree symbol you can use `\textdegree{}` which gives more of an oval shape than the first option would.

Comment: Nouns used to be typeset with an initial capital letter (in German they still are). Proper Nouns (=names of people, places, things) used to be typeset in italics - for ship names (the *Enterprise*), book titles (*The Art of Macros*), newspaper names (the *Daily Planet*), geometrical angles  (*A*) and algebraic quantities (*x*), they still are. And if it looks better typeset as inline maths, because of the italics and special spacing, by all means it's OK. Unrelated: the last letter (or sometimes two) of `folio`, `quarto`, `octavo`, `duodecimo`, are superscripted for the abbreviations.